# How to filter users by userType = null?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to filter out `Guest` users in my Graph query. Since the `ne` comparison operator is not supported I was trying `$filter=userType eq 'Member' or userType eq null` instead. That fails too though. Any known workarounds to list users with `null` as `userType`?

Without that I need to download about a million rows each time and throw 4 out of 5 away on the client side, which is pretty slow and wasteful.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'userType' of resource 'User'.",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "411f7927-c3af-4042-a619-eee1c88971a0",
        "date": "2018-03-17T18:28:35"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update as of June 2021**

the `ne` comparison operator is now supported on userType on graph! So you can now get users  that are not guest users with this query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType ne 'guest'&$count=true`

edit: Important to note that this is an [advanced query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http) as so it requires the header `ConsistencyLevel` to be set to `eventual` and include the $count=true query parameter

here is a link to [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users%3F%24filter%3DuserType%2Bne%2B%27guest%27%26%24count%3Dtrue&method=GET&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&headers=W3sibmFtZSI6IkNvbnNpc3RlbmN5TGV2ZWwiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImV2ZW50dWFsIn1d) with the query that you can run

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an `Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'userType' of resource 'User'.` error when I try that. Curious if anyone else has gotten this to work.

Comment: @GregW does the graph explorer link work for you? It works fine for me. Make sure you are including the header ConsistencyLevel:Eventual as well as the $count parameter. If you dont want only the count of users you can add the $count parameter on the end like this: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType ne 'guest'&$count=true`

Comment: I see, it's working for `/users/$count` but not simply `/users`. I need the actual users, not just the count of them. That's too bad.

Comment: @GregW this query will get you the actual users: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$filter=userType ne 'guest'&$count=true`
Note the $count=true parameter on the end

Comment: Adding $count=true does work, so thanks for that. What I find interesting is how many little edge cases the graph will not support. For example I can use `$count` and `$filter` together, or I can use `$count` and `$expand`, but I cannot use all three of those together. (I'm trying to fetch users while expanding their `manager`, while also filtering out guests.)

Comment: For example this would be a more or less ideal query for what I'm trying to accomplish. Returns the "Unsupported or invalid query" until I remove the expand. `/v1.0/users?$count=true&$filter=userType%20ne%20%27guest%27&$expand=manager($select%3Did)&$select=id,email,givenName,surname,jobTitle,mail,department,city`.

Comment: @GregW try adding the $levels=max; parameter along with your $select inside the $expand. The following works fine for me. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$count=true&$filter=userType ne 'guest'&$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id)&$select=id,email,givenName,surname,jobTitle,mail,department,city`

Comment: Wow, that worked. What black magic is this?? Thank you so much for the continued follow ups.

Comment: "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'userType' of resource 'User'

Comment: @OferGal please read through the comments. Greg was getting the same error as that and got it resolved

Comment: At one point I got the query to work only in Chrome but not in EDGE. the PowerShell snippet gives error "Invalid filter clause"  and  Today same query and even simpler " https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users" gives : Bad Request - 400                                                              How can we rely on such service?

Answer (score 5):

As a general rule of thumb, `userType` should be either `Member` or `Guest`. The exception to this is when you're syncing an on-prem Active Directory. Since `userType` is an Azure AD property, the value for a synced user will be `null`.

If you can safely assume that your on-prem users are *not* guests, you can filter Azure AD user's based on if they're synced or cloud-native. You do this by looking at the `onPremisesSyncEnabled` property. For synced users, this will be `true`, for cloud-native users it will be `null`.

If you combine this with the `userType` property, you can effectively retrieve only non-guest users using the following `$filter`:

```
$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true OR userType eq 'Member'
```

You can also avoid this entirely if you [Enable synchronization of UserType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnectsync-change-the-configuration#enable-synchronization-of-usertype) in [Azure AD Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect).

Comment: Just for anyone who wants to relly on this filter, I had a case when both `onPremisesSyncEnabled` and `userType ` are set to null for regular users.