# userType field - which values are allowed?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph API's User entity has field "userType". According to documentation there is no any information about this. There is one line: "A string value that can be used to classify user types in your directory, such as “Member” and “Guest”. Supports $filter.". So there is no any limitations :-)

1. Can be "userType" null? I can't PATCH existing user manually via graph api - graph api return an error. But on production we have some users, which have "userType": null
2. Which values are valid for "userType"? Can you provide it in documentation or here please?

Comment: Here is also a same question with an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340485/how-to-filter-users-by-usertype-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your questions, I suppose you want to know the valid value of the field `userType`. we can refer to the content of [User Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity).

For your first question, we can set the field `userType` to null, not " " or "null". When we create a user, the default value of this field will be `Member` if we didn't set it.
We can `patch` existing user. Based on my test, we can modify it like this:

`PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}`

```
  {

            "displayName":  "XXX",

            "givenName": "XXXX",

            "jobTitle": "Marketing Director",

            "userType": "Guest"

 }
```

This will modify the user'userType from `Member` to `Guest`.

For your second question, according to the content of [User Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) and the article of [Azure AD User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/user-properties), the valid value for `userType` is "Member" and "Guest". Based on my test, it is sure that only these two values can be used.

Comment: Thank you for great answer!

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you? If so, Could you mark me as answer.

Comment: I had a case when both `onPremisesSyncEnabled` and `userType ` are set to null for regular users.