# error Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'userType' of resource 'User'. Microsoft Graph SDK Filter()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am Microsoft Graph API/SDK to retrieve users from Azure Active Directory. My Filter() function giving me error Message: Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'userType' of resource 'User'.

My code is:

```
var azureUsers = await graphClient
              .Users
              .Request().Filter("startsWith(userType, 'P')")
              .Select(x => new
              {
                x.Id,
                x.UserType,
                x.DisplayName,
                x.GivenName,
                x.Surname,
                x.UserPrincipalName,
                x.AccountEnabled,
                x.Identities,
                x.BusinessPhones,
                x.JobTitle,
                x.MobilePhone,
                x.OfficeLocation,
                x.PreferredLanguage,
                x.Mail,
                x.Extensions,
                x.CreatedDateTime
              })
              .GetAsync();
```

It works absolutely fine with

```
.Filter("startsWith(mail, 'P')")
```

But not with the user type.

I have this attribute UserType in my Azure AD

Our guest users are around 700 and I want to exclude them in call.

It's giving me correct values with

```
        x.UserType,
```

But I want to filter this in Call. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**You are seeing this error, because this filter is not supported for `UserType` attribute - as the error message explains.**

*As a general rule of thumb, `userType` should be either `Member` or `Guest`.* The **exception** to this is when you're syncing an **on-prem Active Directory**. Since `userType` is an Azure AD property, the value for a synced user will be null.

If you can safely assume that your on-prem users are not guests, you can filter Azure AD user's based on if they're synced or cloud-native. You do this by looking at the `onPremisesSyncEnabled` property. For synced users, this will be true, for cloud-native users it will be null.

If you combine this with the `userType` property, you can effectively retrieve only non-guest users using the following $filter:

```
$filter=onPremisesSyncEnabled eq true OR userType eq 'Member'
```

You can check out Marc's answer on the same - [How to filter users by userType = null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340485/how-to-filter-users-by-usertype-null)

Comment: Thank you Harsha, Actually I did this with the same approach after getting data from Azure Ad I have filtered on the basis of On Premises Sysnc Enabled. But I was curious if this can be embedded with the calling filter method to reduce the load on the call. I mean if it's returning less data I'll need less time to wait for the results.

Comment: It is not supported, this is the only way I could find.

Comment: This really worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to get the users list without guest user and according to document  usertype should member or guest.please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

[image]

```
 public static async Task ListUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Getting list of users...");
                // Get all users (one page)
                var result = await graphClient.Users
                    .Request()
                    .Select(e => new
                    {
                        e.DisplayName,
                        e.Id,
                        e.Identities
    
    
                    }).Filter($"usertype eq 'Member'")
                    .GetAsync();
    
                foreach (var user in result.CurrentPage)
                {
                    var directoryObject = await graphClient.DirectoryObjects[user.Id].Request()
                         
     .GetAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(directoryObject));
                }
    
            }
```